# "Artin Theorem" Counterexample

Tags: galois-theory

In the Galois Course on Coursera "Artin's Theorem" (I could not find a reference so I don't know if this is standard terminology) is given:

Let $F$ be a field and $G$ a subgroup of $\text{Aut} (F)$ with $|G|=n$. Then $|F:F^G|=n$ and $G=\text{Gal}(F/F^G)$ where $F^G$ is the subfield fixed by $G$.

But consider the subgroup $H$ of $\text{Aut} (\mathbb{C})$ generated by the element which sends $z \mapsto -z$.

Then $|H|=2$, but $\mathbb{C}^H=\{0\} $ so $|\mathbb{C}:\mathbb{C} ^H|\neq 2$.

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$f(z)=-z$ is *not* an automorphism of $\mathbb{C}.$ Note that $f(ab) = -ab,$ but $f(a)f(b) = (-a)(-b) = ab,$ so that $f$ does not typically preserve multiplication.